# Using Python in Sublime Text and can't find terminus to run saved file

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've started reading "Python Crash Course 2nd edition" and I have ran into some problems.

### *Problem A*

After pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, I install `"Package Control: install package"` but the problem occurs when I need to use a terminal command `cd` (change directory) to navigate through my filesystem in a command window and enter some commands.

### *Problem B*

I tried looking it up, the solution I found was beyond confusing to me, saying I needed to install Terminus (which I believe is terminal) but then said to do so by going through the preference tab and selecting package settings, terminus, and then key bindings.

To anyone that can help, please explain this thoroughly to me. I have a strong desire to further my understanding in python. Also here is the source of which I tried to get help from but to no avail I fell even more confused.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-terminal-in-sublime-text-editor/

Also, I don't know rules about links. I do know I got talked down to for sending two photos that were claimed to be not needed. I am simply trying to help those who help by doing such. Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do, but `Package Control: Install Package` will show you a list of packages to install; pick `Terminus` from the list and Terminus will install.

Comment: What OS are you using? You can use your operating system's standard terminal window application. On Windows search for "console" in the search box, on macOS press cmd-space and enter "terminal" in the search box.

Comment: I apologize greatly, I have it figured out now. I was tired and frustrated when I was trying to do this yesterday so I overlooked this. Thank you for helping I appreciate it and once again I apologize for not being informative enough.